# How to know which child collider triggered in parent?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, collider

I have parent object with 3 children. Each children has one collider (BoxColliders actually) marked as triggers each one.

**I want to know in a OnTriggerEnter on the parent side which collider was hit.**

Similar to this question: [How can I determine which Trigger is hit?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124287/how-can-i-determine-which-trigger-is-hit)
But for 3D Colliders (not 2d). As you can see in the accepted answer they used  `Collider2D.IsTouching` but it doesn't seem to exist any analogue method for a [3D Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)

If is not possible, what other solutions are there? What would be the recommended way? I would like to avoid the overhead from methods like `CompareTag` and `SendMessage` if possible.

http://answers.unity.com/answers/1206114/view.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the parent class a `public` method that takes two arguments, a `Collider` and some form of identification for which child was hit (e.g. a `Transform` or `Vector3` or `int id`, depending on what layout the children are in). Then, in each child object, give them a script like

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ChildCollider : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<ParentScript>.OnChildTriggerEntered(other, transform.position);
    }
}
```

and in the `ParentScript` script

```
public void OnChildTriggerEntered(Collider other, Vector3 childPosition) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: The approach is right, but you cannot call *custom script* methods on *`GameObjects`*. `ChildCollider` should store a reference to the instance of the script which method you call.

Comment: Thanks, edited. This is what I get for not testing my scripts in Unity first...

Comment: Also I recommend caching a reference instead of performing expensive `GetComponent` calls every time.